# How to limit the scope of multicast explicitly to 1 hop only?

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

It's my first question here, so my apologies if I asked wrongly.

In my experiment, multiple android devices are connected using WiFi Direct. To make use of the broadcast nature of wireless tx, all the devices join a single multicast group to exchange their information. My intention is to let the sender send only one copy of its information, while all the 1-hop neighbors receives it.

My trouble is, nodes further away are also receiving it.

Consider the example:

A----B----C

at the same time:

A----D

1) connection is done by wifi direct;
2) they join a single multicast group for message exchange.

What I want: if A sends, B and D can receive, not C; if B sends, A and C can receive, not D. Basically the so-called "1-hop broadcast".

What I get: if A sends, B and D receives, B helps relay it (due to mac layer multicast established by udp multicast I guess?) so C also receives it.

I did some search, multicastSocket has a setTimeToLive() method, with parameters as:

0: not sent on network, only local use;

1: only local network, not going through router;

...

But I somehow need something between 0 and 1, so I can limit the tx to only 1-hop. I couldn't find a solution to this.

You might ask why I need to limit the scope. That's for preventing the flooding, thus reducing network resource consumption.

You might ask why not using unicast to each neighbors. This has a scalability issue in terms of neighbor set cardinality, which should be efficiently solved by multicast/broadcast. Unless wifi direct actually "simulates" multicast/broadcast using unicast at mac layer?

You might also ask why don't I create one distinct multicastSocket for each node to let his neighbors join. I have thought about this, but not sure about the complexity of managing all those sockets.

Sorry for having written so long. I'm looking forward for any suggestion.

EDIT:

--- We tried to setTimeToLive(1), but nodes 2 hops away from a sender can still receive the message.

--- We checked the default TTL and confirmed the default value is already 1.

--- My feeling is that TTL doesn't decrease as it goes from hop to hop, it merely limits the transmission within a "local network" i.e., not going through routers. With wireless nodes connected by WiFi Direct, the network may be treated as a single "local network", hence the relay to all multicast group members.

--- So I doubt if there is any way to explicitly limit the transmission hop counts for a multicastSocket.

--- My two UGLY backup plans are:
1) unicast from a sender to each of its 1-hop neighbors; or
2) each node maintains its own multicastSocket, to let each of its neighbors to join. So nodes 2-hops away will join different multicast groups.

But both solutions will cause the creation and close of lots of sockets, and are subject to the scalability issue (i.e., density).

Can anyone suggest any better solutions to do this? Basically the key target is: implement the 1-hop broadcast functionality for wireless nodes to share local information to its 1-hop neighbors.

Best
Zhang Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you have to set the socket option for TTL (Time to Live):

```
u_char ttl;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl,sizeof(ttl))
```

In java you have different options:

MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html#setTimeToLive(int)

Other options:
Use StandardSocketOptions class to set socket options: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#IP_MULTICAST_TTL

To use StandardSocketOptions you need to work with DatagramChannel: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
int ttlValue = 1;
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttlValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply sir! Please allow me to try them out before getting back to you. Best

Comment: I updated my question. Basically setTimeToLive(1) doesn't seem to work, as the default value is already 1. And may I ask if your suggested solutions are identical in terms of functionality --- set time to live ? I doubt the TTL actually decreases from hop to hop, apart from determining whether it can go outside a router or not.

Comment: @ZhangBo, is there a way you can sniff the network with Wireshark or tcpdump in B to see if actually C is receiving datagrams from B?

Comment: I get that you suspect C actually directly overhears A's transmission, I have also thought about this. We are trying to setup the sniff tools for this. Hopefully the MAC frames, if captured, can tell us something. It might take a bit time, and I'll let you know the result. Thanks in advance for you help so far!